# linear mixed model - post hoc tests for categorical variables against fixed value null-hypothesis

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I'm fitting an LME (with `lmer` in R) with one categorical variable that has many (80) different values. A fitting example for my problem would be how weight loss after fasting is distributed across different body parts and organs. I.e. my model would be: `weight change ~ 1+ bodypart + (1|subject)`

A likelihood ratio test tells me that it makes sense to include the categorical variable as predictor.

Now my key question is at what values of the predictor there is a significant/relevant deviation from 0, i.e. in which organs is there a significant change in weight? I first thought the estimates of the predictors for the individual levels of the categorical variables will tell me this. However, if I understand correctly this would only be true if the intercept would be 0.

My intuition is that perhaps estimated marginal means (ie. using `emmeans` in R) could help me here but I would not know how to ask the question correctly (in R and in general).

Answer (score 2):

Ben is correct. But if interested, the `emmeans` way is

```
emm <- emmeans(model, “bodypart”)
contrast(emm, “eff”)
```

This compares each EMM with the grand mean. If you have more than one fixed factor in the model, this’d be the way to go.

Comment: are `~ bodypart` and `"bodypart"` equivalent as second arguments?  (BTW, you have smart-quotes in your answer, which would mess up cutting & pasting - was that intentional?)

Comment: Sorry about the smart quotes. My phone is definitely not smarter than me, though I guess it’s catching up as I get older. Yes, the formula and character specs are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `emmeans` can do this via `emmeans(fitted_model, ~ bodypart)`. However, in this particular case you can get the same results by fitting the model

```
weight_change ~ 0 + bodypart + (1|subject)
```

(a `-1` would work just as well in place of `0`); this instructs R to suppress the model intercept, and in this case would correspond to  the model $\Delta w_{ij} = \beta_i + \epsilon_{1,j} + \epsilon_{2,ij}$ where $j$ denotes subject and $i$ denotes body part.

As a little bit of a [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge/6843#6843), you might want to consider treating body part as a *random effect*; that would make it harder to do classical inference about individual body parts (e.g. get p-values), but it might lead to more accurate estimates and could get you around some of the multiple-testing challenges you'll get from looking at 80 separate hypothesis tests. (If your data set is huge it might not make that much difference.)